# How serialize an object as a value to ObjectNode in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, servlets, jackson

I'm using `jackson` to serialize my object as json. I'm using following code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNodeFactory nodeFactory = new JsonNodeFactory(false);
ObjectNode resNode = new ObjectNode(nodeFactory);

SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
simpleModule.addSerializer(ApplicationVersion.class, new SingleApplicationSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
JsonNode appObject = mapper.valueToTree(appVersion);

resNode.put("status", true);
resNode.put("appObject", appObject);     //This put method is deprecated.
```

But I saw the `put` method with `JsonNode` overload is deprecated.Why following overload of `put` method is deprecated:

```
public JsonNode put(String fieldName, JsonNode value);
```

What is the alternative for that?

---

Also I tried this:

```
String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(appVersion);
resNode.put("status", true);
resNode.put("appObject", jsonStr);
```

But this method puts double quote (`"`) around `appObject` value as a string value.

Comment: The Javadoc states that you should use either `set(String,JsonNode)` or `replace(String,JsonNode)`. Did you try any of those?

Comment: @user3567830: Thanks :) I didn't see that. I find it now. [Documentation Link](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode%29). Thanks again :)

Answer (score 29):

They added a new method for these actions. `ObjectNode.put(String, JsonNode)`

Try instead `resNode.set("appObject", appObject);`.